# AttributeError: 'CorrectorSubwordBert' object has no attribute 'from_huggingface' in Neuspell

Tags: python, nlp, autocorrect

Upon loading hugging face distilbert-base-case for BertChecker to implement autocorrect on custom vocabulary in NeuSpell using,
checker = BertChecker(device="cuda")
checker.from_huggingface(bert_pretrained_name_or_path="distilbert-base-cased", vocab=vocab),
as in docs, it throws an error
AttributeError: 'CorrectorSubwordBert' object has no attribute 'from_huggingface' in Neuspell.
Any suggestions on how to train a autocorrect in NeuSpell on custom vocabulary?